# selecting between subset of data

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, search, sorting

suppose I have `{a,b,c}` between subsets of them:

```
SUB={{a},{b},{c},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c},{a,b,c}}
```

I want to have the complete members in an array for example:

```
array[0]={{a,b,c}}

array[1]={{a,b},{c}}

array[2]={{a},{b,c}}
```

I mean I want to extract the sets which don't have any common member and one array has all the members

I want to reduce the complexity time if I search the whole it will be n*n
but I think recursive writing will reduce the time complexity
but I can't solve how to code the recursive one.
this example was with 3 members I want it for n members.

I know how to extract subsets but I don't know how to fill my array with this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive algorithm doesn't affect complexity. Any recursive algorithm can be implemented with an equivalent iterative algorithm (Computation Theory 101).

Unless you have some prior knowledge (for example, knowing that it is sorted, like it is in your example, might help. If it is, of course), you have no choice but to go through all of them (at worst case).